# Routes in Laravel expecting '{' closure

Tags: php, laravel

I have Laravel application, but there's error on my routes folder with error like below

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting \
>   (T_NS_SEPARATOR)
>       in api.php line 15

And after i open my file, it caused there's `namespace {closure}C:;`

If i remove `namespace {closure}C:;`, there's no error in my app.
Here is my api.php

```
<?php
/**
* @
* @
* @
* @
*
* @
*/

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.2.0', '>=')) {
    error_reporting(32767 ^ 8 ^ 2);
}

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', namespace {closure}C:; //line 15

function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

There's no error if I edit it like below

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user',
function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

How can i fix it? Cause it's not only api.php with that error. All files in routes folder have same error. Honestly,i've found this Laravel app from github.  I download it cause i wanna learn more with Laravel. Thanks in advance.

I use Ubuntu with PHP 7.0.33

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra ` in your code

change

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user',
function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {` //remove this `
    return $request->user();
});
```

to

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Comment: sorry, i type extra ` on my question, but there's no ` on my code. So, i have to remove my `namespace {closure}C:;` on my code?

Comment: @Syarif Can you post your whole route file? and mark line 15.

Comment: yeah, i post my file and mark line 15. any solution?

Comment: @Syarif Caan you tell me why you need `namespace {closure}C:;`

Comment: as my question above, this is not mine and i got this app from github, but after i ran it in my pc it won't work

Comment: Then edit it like you have done for not getting any error, then make changes according to route you can see on `php artisan route:list` command in your console and let me know the result.